# Is there any functionality in PowerShell to provide output in table format

Tags: powershell

I have a text file like this:

```
Name  : Jack
ID    : JJ1
City  : New York

Name  : Kim
ID    : KK1
City  : Las Vegas
```

I want this file output in following way with Power shell

```
Name    ID    City
Jack    JJ1   NewYork
Kim     KK1   Las Vegas
```

How can I do it in PowerShell script? I tried with Import-CSV but could not get success.

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? You should include a [MCVE] of your attempt, and also any error messages and examples of erroneous output and error messages. [SO] is not a code-writing service; we'll help you, but you have to show the effort you've made.

Answer (score 0):

```
clear-host
$array = @()
foreach($line in (Get-Content C:\input.txt)){

    $nline = $line.Split(":") #-replace """":""
    $values = @{
        'Name' = $nline[1]
        'ID'  = $nline[3]
        'City'   = $nline[5]
    }
    
    $array += New-Object PSObject -Property $values
    
}
$array Out-File -Append c:\temp\output.txt
```

Comment: Old school ways and slow on large datasets